# Parameter in like clause JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql, sql-like

I am trying to write a JPQL query with a like clause:

```
LIKE '%:code%'
```

I would like to have code=4 and find

```
455
554
646
...
```

I cannot pass `:code = '%value%'`

```
namedQuery.setParameter("%" + this.value + "%");
```

because in another place I need `:value` not wrapped by the `%` chars. Any help?

Comment: @Manuele Piastra: Is the answer below not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 177):

If you do

```
LIKE :code
```

and then do

```
namedQuery.setParameter("code", "%" + this.value + "%");
```

Then value remains free from the '%' sign. If you need to use it somewhere else in the same query simply use another parameter name other than 'code' .

Comment: For the record, this does not leave you open to JPQL injection attacks because this.value is automatically properly escaped for you.

Comment: This `"%" + this.value + "%"` is what is escaped.

Comment: How do I make this case-insensitive?

Comment: Like Gustavo noticed before, "%...%" is what is getting escaped. Therefore, in a LIKE clause, the pattern will be not %...%, but \%...\% which is wrong. So, this is not a correct answer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 63):

I don't use named parameters for all queries. For example it is unusual to use named parameters in [JpaRepository](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html).

To workaround I use JPQL **CONCAT** function (this code emulate *start with*):

```
@Repository
public interface BranchRepository extends JpaRepository<Branch, String> {
    private static final String QUERY = "select b from Branch b"
       + " left join b.filial f"
       + " where f.id = ?1 and b.id like CONCAT(?2, '%')";
    @Query(QUERY)
    List<Branch> findByFilialAndBranchLike(String filialId, String branchCode);
}
```

I found this technique in excellent docs: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/jpa_overview_query.html

Comment: Note: CONCAT(?2, '%') will add '%' to the end of the parameter, use CONCAT('%', ?2, '%') to add it to the beginning and end of parameter.

Comment: Adding to the comment above, in Oracle the syntax is: `CONCAT(CONCAT('%', ?2), '%')` to add % to the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: Oracle? This is not a native query is it?

Comment: JPQL supports lots of functions. They are translated to native capabilities of RDBMS. Fetch the spec PDF for JPA 2.2: **JSR 338**, section *4.6.17.2 Built-in String, Arithmetic, and Datetime Functional Expressions*

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [JPA LOCATE function](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.1/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#d5e3202).

> **LOCATE(searchString, candidateString [, startIndex])**: Returns the
>   first index of searchString in candidateString. Positions are 1-based.
>   If the string is not found, returns 0.

FYI: The documentation on [my top google hit](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string#LOCATE_-_Locating_Substrings_) had the parameters reversed.

```
SELECT 
  e
FROM 
  entity e
WHERE
  (0 < LOCATE(:searchStr, e.property))
```

Comment: for me the best solution - no concatenation, no SQL injection.

Comment: What if :searchStr is actually a List? Is there a way use LOCATE with lists?

Comment: MySQL text queries are case-insensitive (based on collation of the field), so this actually performs case-insensitive querying without the performance and readability impact of things like `LOWER()`

Answer (score 4):

There is nice like() method in JPA criteria API. Try to use that, hope it will help.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Employees.class);
Root<Employees> rootOfQuery = criteriaQuery.from(Employees.class);
criteriaQuery.select(rootOfQuery).where(cb.like(rootOfQuery.get("firstName"), "H%"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I am late or out of scope but in my opinion I could do it like:

```
String orgName = "anyParamValue";

Query q = em.createQuery("Select O from Organization O where O.orgName LIKE '%:orgName%'");

q.setParameter("orgName", orgName);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Use below JPQL query.

```
select i from Instructor i where i.address LIKE CONCAT('%',:address ,'%')");
```

2. Use below Criteria code for the same:

```java
@Test
public void findAllHavingAddressLike() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = criteriaUtils.criteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Instructor> cq = cb.createQuery(Instructor.class);
    Root<Instructor> root = cq.from(Instructor.class);
    printResultList(cq.select(root).where(
        cb.like(root.get(Instructor_.address), "%#1074%")));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository` as repository interface:

```java
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT t from Customer t where LOWER(t.name) LIKE %:name%")
    public List<Customer> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

}


@Service(value="customerService")
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    //...

    @Override
    public List<Customer> pattern(String text) throws Exception {
        return customerRepository.findByName(text.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just leave out the ''

```
LIKE %:code%
```

Comment: Downvote: not working, this changes the parameter name to code%

Comment: This answer  is very wrong and misleading, you are not allowed to do that in JPA Queries

Comment: Spring Data seems to accept this syntax (in @Query annotations), whereas JPQL does not.

Comment: Wow, this worked for me, NO idea why, seems awful but it works with Spring data when the single quotes made the query return null.

Answer (score 0):

**Use JPQL query.**

```
@Query("select e from Entity e where e.id = ?1 and e.code like CONCAT('%', CONCAT(?2, '%'))")
List<Entity> findByIdAndCodeLike(Long id, String code);
```