# Convert SQL statement 'LIKE' to JPQL statement

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, jpql

I want to write this SQL statement in eclipse JPQL query. It works in SQL but I'm not sure how to write it in eclipse.

```
SELECT * 
FROM hardware h
WHERE h.`Staffid` LIKE '%150%'
```

My staffid in hardware table is a foreign key to staff table's staffid primary key. So the staff in the hardware table is

```
private Staff staff;
```

This is what I write to run my search:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Hardware> searchstaff(Staff a) {
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();             

        Query query = entityManager
            .createQuery("SELECT st from Hardware st where st.staff LIKE :x");
        query.setParameter("x", a);

        List<Hardware> list = query.getResultList(); 
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();         
        return list;                     
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But it shows

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: Transaction is currently active
```

when I run the search.

Can anyone help me correct?

Answer (score 5):

The like operator work only with string. So do something like that:

```
Query query = entityManager
    .createQuery("SELECT st from Hardware st where st.staff.id LIKE :x");
query.setParameter("x", '%' + a.getId() + '%');
```

Link :

- [Documentation](http://blogs.oracle.com/JPQL01/entry/how_to_use_like_expression)
- [More documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_like)
- [Parameter in like clause JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341104/parameter-in-like-clause-jpql)