# How do i do a like statement in ejb-ql?

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, ejbql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameter in like clause JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341104/parameter-in-like-clause-jpql)

I got this code from an example, how do i do a search with ebj ql?

```
SELECT OBJECT(p)
FROM Person p
WHERE (p.name LIKE ?1)
```

How do i continue from here? I would like to return results where p.name contains string "test"

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. here is an example.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM TestEntity c WHERE   c.titleLIKE :searchString");
query.setParameter("searchString", "%" + "test" + "%");
```