# How to use a like in JPQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to figure out how to use a like with a named query in JPA / Spring 4. So far I have the following...

```
@NamedQuery(name = "MyClass.listItems",
  query = "SELECT DISTINCT(a.name) FROM MyClass a where a.name like ?1")
```

The problem is I need the `%` at the end and I am not sure how to add it. I tried `like ?1%` but this gives a compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341104/parameter-in-like-clause-jpql) that works, kind of...

```
@NamedQuery(name = "MyClass.listItems",
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT(a.name) FROM MyClass a where a.name like CONCAT(?1, '%')")
```

Problem here is it only works if after (which is fine in my case). I think you could chain a Concat if you wanted to but haven't tried yet.

Comment: That's basically right and not a Spring related issue actually. JPQL doesn't support `%` in like expressions inside the query. The `%`es have to be applied to the value bound to the parameter. The Spring Data JPA adds some additional capabilities to that (see the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query) for more details).