# How to correctly convert JPQL query using "%"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I have this query (works fine):

```
@Override
public List<Product> getProductsByName(String name) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productName LIKE '%"+name+"%'");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Product> pro = q.getResultList();
    return pro;
}
```

but I want to convert it into this (with .setParameter()):

```
@Override
public List<Product> getProductsByName(String name) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productName LIKE %:name %")
    .setParameter("name", name);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Product> pro = q.getResultList();
    return pro;
}
```

In this case i get:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: %

How corectly use %  (I tried '%:name%', '%':name'%') ?

Comment: Similar one, refer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1344198/366964

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this way :

```
@Override
public List<Product> getProductsByName(String name) {
  Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productName LIKE :name")
  q.setParameter("name", '%'+name+'%');
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<Product> pro = q.getResultList();
  return pro;
}
```