# LIKE - hibernate named queries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, named-query

why I get **syntax error** using this named query :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "event_find", query = "from Event where location.address like str('%'+:address+'%') " +
        "or :address like str('%'+location.address+'%'")
```

and :

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("event_find").setParameter("address", address); // or "%"+address+"%"
```

how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT :**

Event :

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "event_find", query = "from Event where location.address like :address " +
        "or :address like location.address")
})
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "control_station")
public final class Event implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private Location location;
    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    ...

}
```

Location :

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "control_station")
public final class Location implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String address;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    ...
}
```

for example suppose we have three addresses in table `Location` :

1. Spain
2. Madrid, Spain
3. Santiago Bernabeu Stadium, Madrid, Spain

now if I search for **Madrid, Spain**, the result must contains all of the above...

i.e :

where **Spain** like **%Madrid, Spain%** or **Madrid, Spain** like **%Spain%**

where **Santiago Bernabeu Stadium, Madrid, Spain** like **%Madrid, Spain%** or **Madrid, Spain** like **%Santiago Bernabeu Stadium, Madrid, Spain%**

and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you guys, the answer is :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "event_find", query = "from Event where location.address like concat('%', :address, '%') or :address like concat('%', location.address, '%')")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert with Hibernate but for what I know you probably have two problems :

- First I think you need to put the `%` in the `setParameter()` call, not directly in the named query.  This also means you'll end up with two parameters.
- Second, I assume `str()` is not needed since `location.address` is probably already a string.  Moreover, it looks like there is a missing parenthesis at the end of your `str()` call.

So, I would try something like that :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "event_findLike", query = "from Event where location.address like :addressLike " +
    "or :address like '%'+location.address+'%'")
```

and

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("event_findLike").setParameter("addressLike", "%"+address+"%").setParameter("address", address);
```

Answer (score 1):

The named query should be like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "event_findLike", query = "from Event where location.address like str(:address) " +
        "or :address like :locationAddress
```

you should not use `%` in this named query.

You can use the `%` symbol while setting the parameters like this:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("event_findLike")
.setParameter("address", '%'+address+'%')
.setParameter("locationAddress", '%'+locationAddress+'%');
```

In this code replace `address` and `locationAddress` with your variables that contain required information.

Also refer to this link for similar information: [How to correctly convert JPQL query using "%"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137496/how-to-correctly-convert-jpql-query-using)