# HQL case insensitive like

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, sql-like, case-insensitive

I'm trying to get my `@NamedQuery` to filter some results (for an autocomplete) and I'm able to compare lower case, but I can't seem to shoehorn a `like` in there. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name="customer.by.partial.lower.name", 
            query="from Customer where lower(name) like '%'+lower(:partial)+'%'")
```

I've tried a lot of different variations:

```
lower(name) like lower(%:partial%)
lower(name) like %lower(:partial)%
```

And I've tried every version I can think of, but each one has its own problems. Is there some way to perform a case-insensitive like query in HQL? Please do not suggest I use a Criteria. I need to keep my queries at the top of the class for maintenance reasons.

Comment: The following article may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341104/parameter-in-like-clause-jpql

Comment: @neal Ah, I searched many different posts but that one didn't come up. It did, however, solve the problem. Thanks!