# JPA Repository Query Containing Ignore Case

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm writing a select query using Spring JPA. I'm passing in parameters to compare to an entry in the database. Where I'm running into problems (doesn't compile) is when I try combining UPPER() with the contains (%value%). E.g. %UPPER(value)%

```
where ... AND (UPPER(l.name1) LIKE %UPPER(:search1)% OR UPPER(l.name2) LIKE %UPPER(:search2)% OR UPPER(l.name3) LIKE %UPPER(:search3)%
```

search1, search2, and search3 are parameters being passed in from my service implementation. Is there a different way of getting this logic of contains ignore case in the query? Or am I missing something small? I've tried finding examples but couldn't find any that relate directly to this situation.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not supposed to wrap the SQL function (`UPPER`) with `%` but the literal value.

In any case the can overcome your problem using `CONCAT` function:

`...AND (UPPER(l.name1) LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(UPPER(:search1), '%'))...`

Also, note that you have an extra left parenthesis. You will probably have to add an extra `)` just after `LIKE %UPPER(:search3)%`

Inspired by [Parameter in like clause JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341104/parameter-in-like-clause-jpql?answertab=oldest#tab-top)