# translate sql to JPQL

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, jpql

i m a total newbie to JPQL ,so i m working on a Spring Boot app and i have this SQL query part :

```
select TOP 10 RFC_NUMBER, RECIPIENT_ID from [50004].SD_REQUEST S
INNER JOIN [50004].AM_EMPLOYEE E
--ON S.RECIPIENT_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE E.AVAILABLE_FIELD_5  ='j.doe'  
        AND SD_REQUEST.STATUS_ID NOT IN (8,6,18,7,24)
        AND SD_REQUEST.RFC_NUMBER like 'I%'
```

to JPQL.

i tried doing a @Query like this :

```
   @Query("select x from Incident x  Left join x.recipient recip where recip.login=:login and (x.rfcnumber like :I_% or :rfcnumber = null )"
+ " and x.status NOT IN (8,6,18,7,24)")
```

but it only returns ALL the rfcnumber of the that employee , i want it to extract only the rfc number starting with letter I , 
i tried doing CONCAT from searching around in then web, same thing.
i m new to this so i figure it'll be something much simpler , i m thinking it's just syntax problem .

Thanks a bunch.

Edit (adding models):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="SD_REQUEST")
public class Incident implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -8235081865121541091L;


@Id
@Column(name="REQUEST_ID")
private Integer inid;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SUBMITTED_BY")
private Employee sender;


@Column(name="RFC_NUMBER")
private String rfcnumber;

@Column(name="CREATION_DATE_UT")
private Date date;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@Column(name="COMMENT")
private String comment;

@Column(name="STATUS_ID")
private Integer status;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "RECIPIENT_ID")
private Employee recipient;

public Incident()
{

}

public Incident(int inid,String rfcnumber,Date date,String description,String comment,Integer status)
{
    this.inid=inid; 
    this.rfcnumber= rfcnumber;
    this.date=date;
    this.description=description;
    this.comment=comment;
    this.status=status;

}

public int getInid() {
    return inid;
}

public void setInid(int inid) {
    this.inid = inid;
}

public String getRfcnumber() {
    return rfcnumber;
}

public void setRfcnumber(String rfcnumber) {
    this.rfcnumber = rfcnumber;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Employee getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(Employee sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public Employee getRecipient() {
    return recipient;
}

public void setRecipient(Employee recipient) {
    this.recipient = recipient;
}

public void setInid(Integer inid) {
    this.inid = inid;
}
```

}

And here's the model for Employee :

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@Entity
@JsonDeserialize(as =Employee.class)
@Table(name = "AM_EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5071617893593927440L;

@Id
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID" )
private Integer id;


@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;


@Column(name = "AVAILABLE_FIELD_5")
private String login;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="sender")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Incident> myCreatedIncidents;  
@OneToMany(mappedBy="recipient")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Incident> myOtherIncidents;

@Column(name = "PASSWD")
private String password;

public Employee() {
//super();
}

public Employee (String login,String password)
{

}
public Employee(Integer id, String lastName,String login, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;

}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the lastName
 */
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

/**
 * @param lastName
 *            the lastName to set
 */
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

/**
 * @return the login
 */
public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

/**
 * @param login
 *            the login to set
 */
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

/**
 * @param password
 *            the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public List<Incident> getMyCreatedIncidents() {
    return myCreatedIncidents;
}

public void setMyCreatedIncidents(List<Incident> myCreatedIncidents) {
    this.myCreatedIncidents = myCreatedIncidents;
}

public List<Incident> getMyOtherIncidents() {
    return myOtherIncidents;
}

public void setMyOtherIncidents(List<Incident> myOtherIncidents) {
    this.myOtherIncidents = myOtherIncidents;
}
```

}

Comment: Why not LOOK AT THE SQL invoked? and then you can compare whether you have it right. Nobody can tell you the JPQL without you posting the classes/fields

Comment: i shall edit the post to include the beans too .

Comment: Is 'I' a parameter here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hard-coded characters

I think you should use the same as in SQL:

> like 'I%'

Specifically, according to the article @ http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string#LIKE_-_String_Pattern_Matching_with_Wildcards_ :

> The percent character (%) - which matches zero or more of any character.
>   Blockquote

So try the following:

```
   @Query("select x from Incident x  Left join x.recipient recip where recip.login=:login and (x.rfcnumber like 'I%' or :rfcnumber = null )"
+ " and x.status NOT IN (8,6,18,7,24)"
```

)

### Parameters

See the solutions @ [Parameter in like clause JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341104/parameter-in-like-clause-jpql) if you are using a parameter.

**Examples:**

> LIKE :code%

Also other examples are included in the stackoverflow question.

Comment: Hello
i tried that first hand already, i already checked both links yesterday and tried to do what was shown, but it's still the same. showing all the Rfc number results regardless of the first letter. thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

@Query("select x from Incident x where x.recipient.login=:login and (x.rfcnumber like I% or x.rfcnumber = null )"
+ " and x.status NOT IN (8,6,18,7,24))"

try this query

Comment: I is the first letter of a certain rfc number .. there are numbers in the form of I141103_0002 or R141103_0002 Etc.. so yeah i want to pull only the ones with I 

and i already tried that query , it's not returning the result i seek, logically, it should, but for some reason, the results i get are the all the numbers. ,the LIKE seems to not to apply